# find a nonconstant polynimial function h such that...

Tags: functions, polynomials

I dint know where to start my teacher just threw this at us without much explanation please help.

h(1)=h(2)=h(3)=h(4)=0

Answer (score 2):

Define $h(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.
For any nonconstant polynomial $h(x)$ with real coefficients, if $h(a)=0$ then $h(x)=(x-a)g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is again a polynomial. You can use this argument for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Deliasaghi showed, you can construct a polynomial that gives gives zeros at the desired values by constructing it in terms of factors.

Another approach is to invoke trigonometry. For example, we know that sin(2$\pi$) = 0. Thus, define your function to be,

f(x) = sin(2$\pi$x).

f(x) is not only zero for 1,2,3,4; it is zero for all integers.

Comment: While it's a good answer, the original question refers to polynomials, not any function.

Comment: good observation! Thank you for pointing that out.